# Unable to connect to Google SQL over SSL

Tags: mysql, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I created a fresh instance of google sql with mysql 5.7. I also had to create a client certificate as well as reset the root password to something known and secure.

If I disable "Only allow secure connections" and I log in from the cli then I can connect with the password.

`mysql -uroot -p -h x.x.x.x`

But, i like secure connections. So connecting via ssl (enabling ssl connections and using the downloaded certs) is unable to connect.

`mysql -uroot -h x.x.x.x --ssl-ca=server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem`

with this error

`mysql: [ERROR] SSL error: Unable to get certificate from 'client-cert.pem'
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: Unable to get certificate`

If I try and connect via ssl in mysql administrator, I get this error:

[image: no sql for you]

The certs were created by the google console and am trying to connect how the example command tells me to connect. So I cannot for the life of me figure out why I cannot connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when creating a client certificate, Google Cloud is putting the CRT inside the client-key.pem and the KEY inside the client-cert.pem.

Does it work if you try the following?

`mysql -uroot -h x.x.x.x --ssl-ca=server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-key.pem --ssl-key=client-cert.pem`

Comment: This was in fact the problem. Thanks. Checking the `client-key.pem` and `client-cert.pem` content rsa headers to verify the contents were basically swapped. So I just renamed the files to each other and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this. I filed a public issue tracker for this to fix it:  https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=158